# Message "npm WARN config global `--global + UNABLE TO SAVE: DENIED ACCESS

Tags: node.js, web-development-server, access-denied

I'm trying to learn web developement following some instructions by online course and I have the following problem when I try to comprove if **npm** is working:

C:\Users\Leo>npm --version
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.11.0

So I read that I have to change that **prefix -g** and use "--location=global" but when I try to save it using sublime text the next message appears:
**UNABLE TO SAVE BLABLABLA... npm.cmd

ERROR: ACCESS DENIED**.
please, how can I solve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the editor (sublime text) with administrator privileges